# Is it possible to create an Electorn application that compiles only to the platform code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I will clarify my question for a very specific use case.

Let's say, I've designed my code as follows:

[image]

And this is the content:

src/inner/inner.darwin.ts:

```
export default function logger() {
    console.log('Darwin Logger');
}
```

src/inner/inner.windows.ts:

```
export default function logger() {
    console.log('Windows Logger');
}
```

src/inner/inner.ts:

**NOTE the export default - it is mandatory**

```
import LOGGER from '???????????';

export default class A {
    public static logger() {
         LOGGER();
    }
}
```

So basically, when I compile Windows code, I want to import the `inner.windows.ts` code. When using Mac code - `inner.darwin.ts` code.

I do know I can control excluded files in `tsconfig.json`.
So when I'm going to create Windows application I will code:

```
"exclude": ["**/*.darwin.ts"]
```

And when I will create Mac one:

```
"exclude": ["**/*.windows.ts"]
```

However, it did not help for resolving the import issue.

I do know I can run code depends on the underlying platform using `process.platform`, but it does not do the job. I want the output Windows application to be more small of size - and ignore any Mac code. If I'd use this `process.platform` - the Mac code would still exist in the underlying Windows application.

Any advice?

Can Webpack do something to help?
I am open for any code changes as long as the code is well defined and split, and the final outcome is that I have only Darwin code and Windows code

Comment: "the Mac code would still exist in the underlying Windows application." So what? The vast majority of the size of your application is going to be the executable runtime, and not your javascript code. I have an electron app that is 52MB compressed, with like 1MB of uncompressed code. And any platform specific code you have is probably a tiny fraction of that. One of the major perks of a cross platform framework like Electron is that you _don't_ have to do this sort custom compilation for each platform. The same codebase just works on all platforms.

Comment: @AlexWayne That's a nice notice, but I still do need it

Comment: Can you clarify why you need it to be this way? Is there a conflict between the 2 versions? If so, it may be easier/better to refactor the code in a way that they can coexist.

Comment: @phuzi My only purpose is to make the application smaller. That's all. The 2 versions do the same thing - but the way they do it is different and OS dependent. But they share the same logic. In the example above, imagine I'd use some made up command `windows.logger('blabla')` and `darwin.logger('blabla')`

Comment: And how much of the application size do you think you'd save?

Comment: @phuzi This should be scalable application that grows very rapidly to more and more features. I did note the very first comment. Still need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the solution is quiet simple. All I had to do is using a Webpack plugin.
The best Plugin to fit this task is `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` which is provided out of the box by Webpack itself.

The `exclude` in `tsconfig.ts` is no longer reasonable within this solution.

Simply provide the following plugin:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /darwin/,
    function (resource) {
    resource.request = resource.request.replace(
        /darwin/,
        'windows',
    );
    }
),
```

This will override any import to a `darwin` file into a `winodws` file.

Now, in development, both files exist - but in compilation - only either of them will exist.

`inner.ts` simply becomes:

```
import LOGGER from './inner.darwin';

export default class A {
    public static logger() {
         LOGGER();
    }
}
```

Of course that could be quiet cumbersome to go into `webpack.config.ts` each build, so we could definitely run some extra webpack script to decide upon which underlying build to go with, for example:

```
 const appTarget = env.APP_TARGET || 'darwin';
```

And then simply use this variable within the plugin, and run your npm build script providing an `APP_TARGET` argument.